# ng-repeat displays only the first one item from objects array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, sqlite, cordova

I am working with a `cordova` app that will display the list of items in the cart coming from the `sqlite` database of the device. I am actually using `cordova-sqlite-plugin` for this project.

This is the `json` output

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "prod_id": 1,
            "prod_name": "2 in 1 Retractable USB cable 2",
            "prod_price": 299,
            "prod_img": "img/prod/2_in_1_retractable.png",
            "discount": 50,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "prod_id": 2,
            "prod_name": "2 in 1 Screen Protector",
            "prod_price": 199,
            "prod_img": "img/prod/2_in_1_screen_protector",
            "discount": 50,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "prod_id": 3,
            "prod_name": "3 in 1 USB Charging cable",
            "prod_price": 199,
            "prod_img": "img/prod/usb_charging_cable.png",
            "discount": 50,
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ],
    "count": 11
}
```

**EDIT**

This is a the complete content of `<a ng-repeat=" ..">` in the `html`

```
    <a class="item item-thumbnail-left item-button-right" href="#" ng-repeat="cart in carts">
      <img src="http://{{host}}/{{cart.prod_img}}">
      <h2>{{cart.prod_name}}</h2>
      <p>Php {{cart.prod_price}}</p>
      <button class="button-positive mini-button button-small" style="margin-top: 9px"
        ng-click="change_quantity('inc', $index, cart.prod_id, cart.prod_price, cart.discount, cart.order_limit, cart.invntry_qty)">
        <i class="icon ion-plus"></i>
      </button>
      <input type="number" class="mini-input" style="margin-top: 9px" ng-change="alert('quantity_inputted');"
        ng-model-options="{debounce:1000}">
      <button class="button-positive button-small mini-button" style="margin-top: 9px; margin-right: 8px;"><i class="icon ion-minus"></i></button>
      <button class="button-small button-positive remove icon-left ion-trash-b" style="margin-top: 9px"
        ng-click="remove_to_cart(cart.prod_id)">&nbspRemove</button>
    </a>
```

`controller.js`

```
$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "SELECT prod_id, prod_name, prod_price, prod_img, discount, quantity FROM cart;")
.then(function(res) {

  if (res.rows.length > 0) {
    cart.items = new Array();
    for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
      cart.items.push({
        prod_id: res.rows.item(i).prod_id,
        prod_name: res.rows.item(i).prod_name,
        prod_price: res.rows.item(i).prod_price,
        prod_img: res.rows.item(i).prod_img,
        discount: res.rows.item(i).discount,
        quantity: res.rows.item(i).quantity
      });
    }
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    cart.count = cart.items.length;
    alert(JSON.stringify(cart));
    alert("cart count: " + cart.items.length);
  }
  alert("app.js - Success Fetching Cart");
  console.log("app.js - Success Fetching Cart");
}, function(error) {
  console.log("app.js - Failed Fetching Cart");
});
```

After fetching the json from db. I put them to $scope.

```
$scope.carts = cart.items;
```

The problem is the ng-repeat only display the first one item which has the `prod_id:1`. The `json` seems fine and I don't know what seems wrong with my `js` and `html` code. I've taken json output from the `alert(JSON.stringify(cart));`.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the error of the program..

```
[INFO:CONSOLE(20434)] "Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.13/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange
```

Sorry for not stating so soon. The reason for this is I did not put an `ng-model` in the `<input>` which is inside the `<a ng-repeat=' ..'>`. So I changed it into:

```
<input type="number" 
class="mini-input" 
style="margin-top: 9px" 
ng-change="alert('quantity_inputted');"
ng-model-options="{debounce:1000}" 
ng-model="cart.quantity">
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not looping throught the array which exist inside the carts object. Below is the working code

```js
      var myapp = angular.module("app",[]);
      myapp.controller("displayCarts",function($scope){

            $scope.carts = {
    "items": [
        {
            "prod_id": 1,
            "prod_name": "2 in 1 Retractable USB cable 2",
            "prod_price": 299,
            "prod_img": "img/prod/2_in_1_retractable.png",
            "discount": 50,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "prod_id": 2,
            "prod_name": "2 in 1 Screen Protector",
            "prod_price": 199,
            "prod_img": "img/prod/2_in_1_screen_protector",
            "discount": 50,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "prod_id": 3,
            "prod_name": "3 in 1 USB Charging cable",
            "prod_price": 199,
            "prod_img": "img/prod/usb_charging_cable.png",
            "discount": 50,
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ],
    "count": 11
};

      });
```

```html
<html>

   <head>
      <title>AngularJS HTML DOM</title>
   </head>

   <body>


      <h2>AngularJS Sample Application</h2>

      <div ng-app = "app" ng-controller="displayCarts">

       <a class="item item-thumbnail-left item-button-right" href="#" ng-repeat="cart in carts.items">
  <h2>{{cart.prod_name}}</h2>
  <p>Php {{cart.prod_price}}</p>
</a>


      </div>

      <script src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
      
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine as per the `JSON` provided in the Original Post.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.carts = [
        {
            "prod_id": 1,
            "prod_name": "2 in 1 Retractable USB cable 2",
            "prod_price": 299,
            "prod_img": "img/prod/2_in_1_retractable.png",
            "discount": 50,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "prod_id": 2,
            "prod_name": "2 in 1 Screen Protector",
            "prod_price": 199,
            "prod_img": "img/prod/2_in_1_screen_protector",
            "discount": 50,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "prod_id": 3,
            "prod_name": "3 in 1 USB Charging cable",
            "prod_price": 199,
            "prod_img": "img/prod/usb_charging_cable.png",
            "discount": 50,
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <a class="item item-thumbnail-left item-button-right" href="#" ng-repeat="cart in carts">
  <h2>{{cart.prod_name}}</h2>
  <p>Php {{cart.prod_price}}</p>
</a>
</div>
```